# Android exception finalizer

Tags: android, ssl, dalvik, finalizer

I've been receiving this error and I can't figure out why I have. It doesn't cause the app to crash but I'm not sure if it is affecting my app or not.

```
05-03 16:29:20.962  31355-31366/com.example.apthagreat.faf E/System﹕ Uncaught
exception thrown by finalizer
05-03 16:29:20.972  31355-31366/com.example.apthagreat.faf E/System﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: ssl == null
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:794)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:85)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.flush(PGStream.java:531)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ProtocolConnectionImpl.close(ProtocolConnectionImpl.java:143)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.close(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:644)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.finalize(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:1003)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:194)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: so what's the question ?

Comment: It is hard to tell if it is affecting your app somehow. For sure NullPointerException is not a good thing, but without a specific piece of code I can't tell anything more.

Comment: That's the thing I don't know where its causing this and I'm not sure what it means

Comment: To find out where it is causing place some Log.d(TAG, "Step 1: "); & Log.d(TAG, "Step 2: "); and so on...

Answer (score 0):

In the Java programming language, exceptions thrown by finalizers are discarded.  That seems like a great way for failures to go unnoticed, so the Android VM logs a message letting you know that a problem is being ignored.

If the NullPointerException is being thrown because resources have already been released and nulled out, then this is a minor logic issue.  If it's being thrown because something is in a bad state, then you could have a bigger problem.  The log message just tells you that there's something needing investigation.

Since this error is occurring during what appears to be a database flush-before-close, it's possible you're losing data because the SSL connection is being closed before the database.